# How to Send Periodic Ephemeral ("Hidden") Messages From a Slack Bot

Tags: slack-api, slack

I am interested in writing a Slack bot that will periodically send "ephemeral" messages to users.  Ephemeral messages are messages that appear within a channel, but can only be seen by a particular user, like the responses to bot "slash commands" (e.g. "/who").

The goals here, however, are to have ephemeral messages sent periodically by the bot and:

1. appear within the channel message stream (i.e. not in a
   DM/private message), and
2. not in response to any slash command.

How do I use the APIs to create ephemeral messages like this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sending private messages with the "Only visible to you" tag is called "ephemeral" and seems to now be possible through the Slack API.

https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postEphemeral

(I'm not sure since when, and why it still says "Mid Term" on [their roadmap](https://trello.com/c/Xs12hGkH))

Comment: The Trello card has since been updated and was moved from "Mid Term" to "Released" on Nov 3, 2017